# Don't you think Captain Construction should be our official logo?

Tags: discussion, logo

Drawn by our very own [Aarthi Devanathan](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/3312/aarthi-devanathan) in the DIY Chat room, this superhero depicts all that is awesome about those who engage in DIY.

Sure he's a little rough around the edges, but don't you think he should be our "official" mascot?

[image]

Comment: That Philips head screwdriver needs to be a little less lifelike though...

Comment: @NiallC. LOL - Take that up with Aarthi! ;)

Comment: Why would you use a logo with a penis(top right gray thing) ??

Comment: Its a screwdriver, ya perv!

Comment: :-) You should reconsider making it a flat head..

Comment: To repeat:  Take that up with Aarthi! ;)

Comment: Make the screwdriver a Torx instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper answer here is yes, people! ;)